# Check if Youtube ID is valid with ColdFusion

Tags: if-statement, youtube, coldfusion

I want to check if a YouTube Link/ID is valid. It should get me an answer with an if / else statement.

I tried this:

```
<cfset variables.key = "my_key_value_here">
<cfset variables.headers = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#variables.key#">

<cfif (IsArray(#variables.headers#) ? ReMatch('(http:\/\/)(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/(?:watch\?|user\/|v\/|embed\/)\S+|\.be\/\S+)',#variables.headers#) : false)>
     Correct Id!
<cfelse>
   There is no video with that Id!
</cfif>
```

The ID in the example is correct and should output: "Correct ID!" But it displays always the else-statement.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: I think Best way to validate youtube video Id by checking it through youtube data API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<cfset variables.key = "my_key_value_here">
<cfhttp method="Get" url="https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#variables.key#">
<cfif cfhttp.statusCode EQ "200 OK">
    Correct Id!
<cfelse>
    There is no video with that Id!
</cfif>

<cfoutput>#cfhttp.statusCode#</cfoutput>
```

I do not need a RegEx because it is always the same link, just another ID.

Comment: Indeed this is simple enough.

Comment: Side note, no need for pound signs in the cfif, or the outer cfoutput tags.

Comment: If all you are checking is the response status, why not use `HEAD` rather than `GET`?

Comment: Is `cfhttp` actually smart enough to encode the value of the `url` part in the query string? The query string here basically contains two question marks.

Answer (score 5):

I think Best way to validate youtube videoId by checking it through youtube data API. Below are the steps you need to follow to validate video.

1. Login to your google Account
2. Go to [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library)
3. In Api library click on YouTube Data API
4. Create a project
5. Create credential for the same project (this will give you API key)
6. Enable API

Once you are done with above steps you can simply implement this API in ColdFusion using [CFHTTP](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html) tag.

Here is a code snippet that can help you.

```
<cfset variables.youtubeId = "EUcaCKWk83Q" />
<cfset variables.youTubeApiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY" />
<cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=#youtubeId#&key=#youTubeApiKey#" >
<cfset response = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent) />
<cfif response.pageInfo.totalResults>
    Correct Id!
<cfelse>
    There is no video with that Id!
</cfif>
```